# Powershell + REST API + Cisco Firepower

Tags: json, powershell, api, cisco

(Please note that IP addresses, account names and account passwords are replaced with "X" in examples below.

I'm trying to manage an API on a Cisco Firepower chassis.  The first request is to receive a password token for more REST API requests.  I am able to get it to work with a direct JSON request from the test page of the device itself.   My task is to take that JSON request and invoke it from another machine through Powershell.

This is the JSON request that works:

```
{
"grant_type": "password",
"username": "xxx",
"password": "xxx"
}
```

When this JSON request is submitted, I get the 200 response I expect from the device, providing me with a message that includes the access token I use for future requests.   It even provides me with the CURL code I would use if I were invoking it from CURL:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
 "grant_type": "password", \ 
 "username": "xxx", \ 
 "password": "xxx" \ 
 }' 'https://x.x.x.x/api/fdm/v5/fdm/token'
```

All I'm really trying to do is duplicate what curl is doing above - but in Powershell, instead, running on a Windows 2019 server box.

This is my powershell code:

```
$param = '{"grant_type":"password","username":"xxx",password":"xxx"}'
$json = $param | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod 'https://x.x.x.x/api/fdm/v5/fdm/token' -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType 'application/json'
```

What I get back APPEARS to be from the Firepower box as an error, but I don't have enough information to tell what it does not like about it, specifically:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server ErrorH1 
{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 
{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 
{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY 
{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B 
{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P 
{font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : 
black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
At line:3 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod 'https://x.x.x.x/api/fdm/v5/fdm/token' -Method P ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

There is no log I can find on the Firepower box itself that shows API requests or errors.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Oh:  below is the "cleaned up" status message:

```
Exception details: 
    Message: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
    Status code: InternalServerError
    Status description: Internal Server Error
    Response:
```

Comment: You forgot a quote in the `$param` declaration. Should be `$param = '{"grant_type":"password","username":"xxx","password":"xxx"}'` Because that is already JSON, you should remove `$json = $param | ConvertTo-Json` and use `$param` for the `-Body` parameter.

Comment: Thank you, Theo!   That does help me out, though it doesn't completely resolve my issue.  After adding the quote in front of the "p" in "password" and not using the CovnvertTo-JSON function on the string, I now get the following error:  Exception details: 
 Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
 Status code: 400
 Status description: Bad Request
 Response: {"message":"Token grant_type is either not-specified or not-supported - null","status_code":400}

Comment: You did use `-Body $param` did you? I am not familiar with that api, so you'll have to investigate what the exact syntax should be..

Comment: Theo - yes, I did.  The API is of course the Cisco Firepower 1120 and this curl string, run from a Ubuntu box, does work:curl --cacert fwcert -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ "grant_type": "password", "username": "xxx", "password": "xxx" }' 'https://xxx/api/fdm/v5/fdm/token'
...... I, however am still getting an Error 400 when I try to send the equivalent through PowerShell